# Building JSON Structure in ESQL IIB/ACE

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Hi Everyone I am trying to build a JSON with following structure in ESQL-

```
{
    "programId": 0,
    "sku": "abc",
    "productTypeId": 0,
    "brand": "string",
    "year_no": 0,
    "characteristics": [
        {
            "characteristicId": 1,
            "value_no": "a"
        },
        {
            "characteristicId": 2,
            "value_no": "b"
        },
        {
            "characteristicId": 3,
            "value_no": "c"
        }
    ]
}
```

[This is my db looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CKCI.png)

Can anyone help me in the ESQL code structure for the particular use case.

Problems I am facing-
When I am using Outputroot.JSON.Data - It is printing Data as root object.
How Should I loop through DB to get this result. I am fetching every record from DB.
Thanks for help!

I am able to get result for one record but when I am looping it for second it is overwriting the previous values.

Also, I have to match and compare first five fields I have to keep them common and build characteristics array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Based on your comments, you want one message on the output terminal when one of the first 5 elements changes the value. The algorithm assumes that your database fields are sorted by the first 5 elements.

Then the code will look like this, see [Creating a JSON message](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=domain-creating-json-message) to understand the details:

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE DbToJson_Compute
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        DECLARE recordJsonItem REFERENCE TO OutputRoot;
        DECLARE characteristicsJsonItem REFERENCE TO OutputRoot;
        DECLARE previousRecordKey CHAR '';
        FOR record AS InputRoot.XMLNSC.doc.record[] DO
            DECLARE programId INT record.programId;
            DECLARE sku CHAR record.sku;
            DECLARE productTypeId INT record.productTypeId;
            DECLARE brand CHAR record.brand;
            DECLARE year_no INT record.year_no;
            DECLARE currentRecordKey CHAR BuildRecordKey(programId, sku, productTypeId, brand, year_no);
            IF currentRecordKey <> previousRecordKey THEN
                IF previousRecordKey <> '' THEN
                    PROPAGATE;
                END IF;
                CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.JSON AS recordJsonItem NAME 'Data';
                SET recordJsonItem.programId = programId;
                SET recordJsonItem.sku = sku;
                SET recordJsonItem.productTypeId = productTypeId;
                SET recordJsonItem.brand = brand;
                SET recordJsonItem.year_no = year_no;
                CREATE FIELD recordJsonItem.characteristics IDENTITY(JSON.Array)characteristics;
                SET previousRecordKey = currentRecordKey;
            END IF;
            CREATE LASTCHILD OF recordJsonItem.characteristics AS characteristicsJsonItem NAME 'Item';
            SET characteristicsJsonItem.characteristicId = record.characteristicId;
            SET characteristicsJsonItem.valueNo = record.valueNo;
        END FOR;
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;

    CREATE FUNCTION BuildRecordKey(programId INT, sku CHAR, productTypeId INT, brand CHAR, year_no INT) RETURNS CHAR
    BEGIN
        RETURN CAST(programId AS CHAR) || sku || CAST(productTypeId AS CHAR) || brand || CAST(year_no AS CHAR);
    END;
END MODULE;
```

I tested this code with following input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
  <record>
    <programId>0</programId>
    <sku>abc</sku>
    <productTypeId>0</productTypeId>
    <brand>string</brand>
    <year_no>0</year_no>
    <characteristicId>1</characteristicId>
    <valueNo>a</valueNo>
  </record>
  <record>
    <programId>0</programId>
    <sku>abc</sku>
    <productTypeId>0</productTypeId>
    <brand>string</brand>
    <year_no>0</year_no>
    <characteristicId>2</characteristicId>
    <valueNo>b</valueNo>
  </record>
  <record>
    <programId>0</programId>
    <sku>abc</sku>
    <productTypeId>0</productTypeId>
    <brand>string</brand>
    <year_no>0</year_no>
    <characteristicId>3</characteristicId>
    <valueNo>c</valueNo>
  </record>
  <!-- second group starts here -->
  <record>
    <programId>0</programId>
    <sku>xyz</sku>
    <productTypeId>0</productTypeId>
    <brand>string</brand>
    <year_no>0</year_no>
    <characteristicId>11</characteristicId>
    <valueNo>aa</valueNo>
  </record>
  <record>
    <programId>0</programId>
    <sku>xyz</sku>
    <productTypeId>0</productTypeId>
    <brand>string</brand>
    <year_no>0</year_no>
    <characteristicId>22</characteristicId>
    <valueNo>bb</valueNo>
  </record>
</doc>
```

This is the first output message:

```
{
  "programId": 0,
  "sku": "abc",
  "productTypeId": 0,
  "brand": "string",
  "year_no": 0,
  "characteristics": [
    {
      "characteristicId": "1",
      "valueNo": "a"
    },
    {
      "characteristicId": "2",
      "valueNo": "b"
    },
    {
      "characteristicId": "3",
      "valueNo": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the second output message:

```
{
  "programId": 0,
  "sku": "xyz",
  "productTypeId": 0,
  "brand": "string",
  "year_no": 0,
  "characteristics": [
    {
      "characteristicId": "11",
      "valueNo": "aa"
    },
    {
      "characteristicId": "22",
      "valueNo": "bb"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you so much for the clarification. But I don't want top-level JSON object array. I want different JSON For different sku. So it should generate 2 different program id's 0 & 1.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Do you need single messages on the output of this compute node, or do you collect all of the JSON objects in memory and send them to the output as one big BLOB?

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry for late reply. I want it as single messages on the output but if there are two different sku's then it should produce two different outputs for the two different sku's